# Why does not reload tableView work swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, reloaddata

**When I call `reloadData()` from `delegate` (or `viewDidLoad`) the function `tableView(...cellForRowAtIndexPath:..)` is not fired. When I call `reloadData()` from tapButton all works. Why?**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        exerciseList = ExerciseListTableViewController.ExerciseList
        trainingList = TrainingListTableViewController.trainingList
        if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "FactoryEx") != 0 {
            identifierFactory = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "FactoryEx")
        }
        tableView.rowHeight = 60
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        //tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    func reload(choose: Bool){
        exerciseTableChoose = choose
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    @IBAction func reload(_ sender: UIButton) {
        exerciseList.append(Exercise())
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
protocol FirstTable {
func reload(choose: Bool)
func addCell(name: String, parametr: [Bool])
}
```

Comment: could be for a number of reasons, count is zero, number of items in section returns 0

Comment: have you implemented 'numberOfRowsForSection'  datasource Method?

Comment: Add the code related to `UITableView` creation and Where you set the Data for `TableView` and reload part. Add the Code for better explanation

Answer (score 0):

add **tableView.reloadData()** in **viewDidAppear()**. because of **viewDidLoad()** only call when Viewcontroller create.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way.

```
extension SCSelectSubTypeVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return datasource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:SCSelectSubTypeCell = self.tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SCSelectSubTypeCell") as! SCSelectSubTypeCell
    cell.confirgureCell(datasource[indexPath.row])
    return cell

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}
```

}

and call self.tblView.reloadData() in viewWillAppear() function if you want to reload table each time the viewController appears.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, UI can update **only in main thread!**